# flot charts - how to mark points on line chart specifying a time

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts, flot

I've made chart with two axes (x and y), axis x is in time mode. Is possible to mark points on line specifying a time? Something like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/46wj0.png

Comment: I found solution. I loaded additional data series with coordinates of points and I set "points" as true.

Comment: Nice!  You can post the answer to your question, and that way other people can benefit from it as well (and you'll get votes!)